# Is the antisymmetrisation of $a^{\mu}b^{\nu}\epsilon_{\mu\nu}= a^{[\mu}b^{\nu]}\epsilon_{\mu\nu}$ with antisymmetric tensor $\epsilon$ mandatory?

Tags: tensor-calculus, poincare-symmetry

When in tensor algebra the product of 2 vectors with a antisymmetric tensor appear, is antisymmetrisation compulsory ? Given an antisymmetric tensor $\epsilon_{\mu\nu}$, is

$$a^{\mu}b^{\nu}\epsilon_{\mu\nu} =  a^{[\mu}b^{\nu]}\epsilon_{\mu\nu}$$

with $a^{[\mu}b^{\nu]} = \frac{1}{2}(a^\mu b^\nu  - a^\nu b^\mu)$ to be done mandatorily?

I will give a concrete example: Guaranteeing the Poincare-covariance of a field $\phi_r$  by

$$U(L)\phi_r U(L)^{-1} = S^{-1}_{rs} (L)\phi_s(Lx)$$

using $U(L) = 1-\frac{i}{2}\epsilon_{\mu\nu} \mathbf{M}^{\mu\nu}$ and $L_{\mu\nu} = g_{\mu\nu} +\epsilon_{\mu\nu}$ ($L_{\mu\nu}$ a Lorentz transformation, $g_{\mu\nu}$  the Minkowski metric tensor) we get:

$$i \epsilon_{\mu\nu}[\mathbf{M}^{\mu\nu}, \phi_r] = \epsilon_{\mu\nu} \Sigma^{\mu\nu}_{rs}\phi_s -2 \phi,^{\tau}\epsilon_{\tau\lambda}x^\lambda $$

Apparently in order to factor out the components of the antisymmetric tensor $\epsilon_{\mu\nu}$ the following antisymmetrisation is done:

$$i \epsilon_{\mu\nu}[\mathbf{M}^{\mu\nu}, \phi_r] = \epsilon_{\mu\nu} \Sigma^{\mu\nu}_{rs}\phi_s +     \phi_r,^{\lambda}\epsilon_{\tau\lambda}x^\tau  -  \phi_r,^{\tau}\epsilon_{\tau\lambda}x^\lambda $$

before the result is obtained:

$$i [\mathbf{M}^{\mu\nu}, \phi_r] =\Sigma^{\mu\nu}_{rs}\phi_s +     \phi_r,^{\nu}x^\mu  -   \phi_r,^{\mu}x^{\nu}$$

Is the antisymmetrisation necessary in order to allow to factor out the antisymmetric $\epsilon_{\mu\nu}$ ? Apart from this particular case I have seen an antisymmetrisation in a couple of cases, 
so my question is not only related with this particular case.

Comment: The contraction of a symmetric and skew-symmetric tensor is zero. On the other hand any tensor can be writren as its symmetric plus skew-symmetric parts. That's the reasoning behind the first equation.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not mandatory. You can choose to add the brackets as a reminder that only the antisymmetric part of $a^\mu b^\nu$ contributes.

Answer (score 0):

It's precisely the opposite of mandatory: it makes absolutely no difference.

> Apparently in order to factor out the components of the antisymmetric tensor $\epsilon_{\mu\nu}$ the following antisymmetrisation is done: 
>   $$i \epsilon_{\mu\nu}[\mathbf{M}^{\mu\nu}, \phi_r] = \epsilon_{\mu\nu} \Sigma^{\mu\nu}_{rs}\phi_s +     \phi,^{\lambda}\epsilon_{\tau\lambda}x^\tau  -  \phi,^{\tau}\epsilon_{\tau\lambda}x^\lambda $$

This is a misunderstanding. We are not changing the expression by antisymmetrizing it, we are just writing it in a different way. The statement $A^{\mu\nu} \epsilon_{\mu\nu} = A^{[\mu\nu]} \epsilon_{\mu\nu}$ is always true, whether $A$ itself is antisymmetric or not.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. But I've still a caveat. If one didn't antisymmetrize one would get for the commutator : $$i [\mathbf{M}^{\mu\nu}, \phi_r] =\Sigma^{\mu\nu}_{rs}\phi_s -  2 \phi_r,^{\mu}x^{\nu}$$ after factoring out $\epsilon_{\mu\nu}$ (instead of $$i [\mathbf{M}^{\mu\nu}, \phi_r] =\Sigma^{\mu\nu}_{rs}\phi_s +     \phi_r,^{\nu}x^\mu  -   \phi_r,^{\mu}x^{\nu}\equiv [S^{\mu\nu} + \cal{L}^{\mu\nu}]\phi$$ where $S^{\mu\nu}$ and $\cal{L}^{\mu\nu}$ are spin and orbital momentum operators) which looks awkward.

Comment: @FredericThomas That equation is wrong, you cannot just "factor out " $\epsilon_{\mu\nu}$, because it annihilates the symmetric part. What you are doing is like starting from the equation $v_x = w_x$ for two vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$, and "factoring out the $x$" to conclude that $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{w}$.

Comment: This is actually what I thought. So prior to factoring out $\epsilon_{\mu\nu}$ I have to antisymmetrize its coefficient to get the $i[\mathbf{M^{\mu\nu}}, \phi_r] = [S^{\mu\nu} +\cal{L}^{\mu\nu}]\phi$. So antisymmetrisation of the coefficient is mandatory, it makes a difference in this context.

Comment: @FredericThomas I still would not say it is "mandatory". The point is, antisymmetrization here does _nothing_ to the equation. However, when both sides are antisymmetrized, you may cancel $\epsilon_{\mu\nu}$ from both sides without error. It is like how, if $|x| = |y|$, you are allowed to "cancel the absolute value signs" and conclude $x = y$ only if you restrict $x$ and $y$ to both be positive. But that does not mean that writing the equation $|x| = |y|$ means this restriction is _mandatory_. The equation makes sense even when $x$ is negative.